# How to get to the pie menus?

Tags: interface, shortcut, pie-menu

With the pie menus, new for blender 2.72, I'm now wondering how do I get to them? I have tried some of the different keyboard shortcuts mentioned for the pie menus.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For 2.72 you have to enable the pie menus in the user preferences. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> or `File -> User preferences` then the *Addons* tab. Search for `pie`, enable the addon called `User Interface: Pie Menus Offical`.

After the pie menu addon is enabled the keyboard shortcuts such as <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> will open a pie menu. Documentation about the pie menus on the [blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.72/UI/Pie_Menus).

Comment: Got your selfie, eh?