# Is it possible to switch objects while still remaining in edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode

When aligning a complex scene with many objects, I currently have to exit edit mode, select the next object, and then select edit mode to then edit that object. Is there any way to stay in edit mode and switch to another object? Is there a plugin that will allow me to do this?

The way I would envision this would work is if I mouse select another object while in edit mode, that object would become the active editable object. This would reduce the extra clicks needed when editing a scene with a large number of objects.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but switching objects doesn't seem that slow to me, unless you are clicking to change to/from edit mode as opposed to `TAB` -> `select object` -> `TAB`

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/outliner.html) editor to press on the buttons next to the object name to enter Edit mode for those objects:

[image: screenshot-triangles-in-a-nice-orange-quad]

It's needed to press exactly that triangle button which shows mesh datablock inside of object datablock. If you click on the object name it will activate Object mode.

Note that this won't allow to bypass switching interaction modes; there will be Edit mode toggle anyway visible in the actions history, it's just that there will be less clicks:

[image: giffy-toggling-edit-mode]

Comment: Yes! Also for models consisting of lots of objects, i add them to groups so that I can easily edit on a subset of the objects and use outliner to switch between them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but currently there is no other way to switch to another object with the exception of using the outliner?

Comment: @RSRAM I think there isn't any direct way. Only one object can be in Edit mode at a time so you could use workarounds like joining objects into groups and editing groups or joining multiple objects into one. I'd also add that if you really want to speed up switching between interaction modes and alike you might find useful [Pie menus](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21044/how-to-get-to-the-pie-menus) addon.